# is it really wrong to release resources in onDestroy?

Tags: android

Android documentation says (in http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html):

> In extreme cases, the system might simply kill your app process without calling the activity's final onDestroy() callback, so it's important you use onStop() to release resources that might leak memory.

Sounds like it is wrong. How could killed process leak memory?

Comment: The main process would be killed but not the some of the requested resources.

Answer (score 8):

Suppose you started a service in your onStart() method, and you intend to stop that service when the user gets out of the Activity.

If you put the code to stop the service in onDestroy(), that code may never get called, which can leave that service running until Android decides to kill it (which may not happen for a while, if ever). That running service is and example of leaking memory/resources outside your application.

You should put cleanup code like that in a method that is guaranteed to be called.

Note that a process is killable after onPause() has been called, so onPause() is really the place you want to do cleanup that absolutely must happen.

(See table 1 in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html for details on the Activity lifecycle)

Another thing that might be really bad to leak: Bluetooth discovery or location reporting (GPS or network-based) turned on but not off as soon as possible - very bad for battery life.

Comment: I should note that Bluetooth discovery will timeout, but it's very battery intensive and you should shut it off as soon as you know you no longer need it. (The timeout can be as long as 300 seconds)

Comment: How can it be that Activity is not freed from memory if process is killed? If process is killed, its VM is killed as well and all its memory is given back to OS.

Comment: @user983447 - good point - I've removed that reference. I wasn't thinking about the manager instance being in the same process. That's more of a problem if the process isn't killed and the developer hadn't unregistered the sensor listeners.

Comment: I just checked - when activity does requestLocationUpdates and then it never does removeUpdates and gets killed, GPS is stopped by Android. So it seems that it's nothing bad to do removeUpdates in onDestroy - even if onDestroy is not called on process being killed, android turns off GPS.

Comment: Another (more important) thing to consider is whether you want the GPS updates (or other started actions) to continue when you call startAcivity() to move to the next activity. In a case like that, the activity may be kept in "stopped" state; onDestroy() wasn't called. It's likely that in your second activity you don't want that original GPS listener. It'll hang around during the second activity even if not needed.